# Can I receive a tax deduction from working from home in a 2 bedroom apartment, one bedroom is used EXCLUSIVELY for work?

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction

My company's base office is in another city so I work from home in a two bedroom apartment. The second bedroom is used as my office and office/work storage. Can I write off this space and any portion of the bills (internet, energy, etc.) associated with this?

Comment: For a tax question, you'll need to tell us what country you're in.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

[This nolo.com article](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/home-office-tax-deduction-30117.html) describes some of the requirements for qualifying for this deduction.

**Note** this deduction is widely abused and is an audit red-flag. You need to be meticulous in keeping documentation related to this deduction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have documentation you can surely claim the expenses as deduction. Since you are working from home, is the company separately reimbursing you such expenses? It is a practice to reimburse such expenses as the company is not able to provide you such facility. It may have been built into your compensation packages. All these issues also make difference. Your legal consultant can only clarify these issues based on the facts.